# How to plot a 3D figure in matlab based on a function like f(x,y,z)=0?

Tags: matlab, function, 3d

How to plot a 3D figure in `MATLAB` based on a function like `f(x,y,z)=0`? 
And this complicated function can not be written as `z = f(x,y)`.

```
f(x,y,z)=sum(a.*exp(sv(:,1)-x).^2+sv(:,2)-y).^2+sv(:,3)-z).^2)-b=0
```

where a is a known vector, sv is a known matrix, b is a known value. x,y,z are three variables. How to draw this surface in 3D way in matlab?

Comment: If you have `x,y,z` already, did you try simply using `surf`? (check the documentation if needed.)

Comment: No, I just got the function without solving it to get the points.

Comment: have you tried with `ezplot`?

Comment: Can you describe more about a and sv. Sample data for example

Comment: I think you should check your expression for f(xyz), it doesn't look right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solve this question by this tool from the Matlab File Exchange:
[Ezimplot3: implicit 3D functions plotter](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23623-ezimplot3-implicit-3d-functions-plotter)

Answer (score 1):

your function only contains 1D vectors( I am assuming they are of equal lengths), if summed it will give you a constant; therefore, there is really nothing to plot.

Comment: I just solve this question by a tool--Ezimplot3: implicit 3D functions plotter  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23623-ezimplot3-implicit-3d-functions-plotter. Thank you guys for your replies.